# Upgrading iPhone App (made in 2009) to New Version (Help Required)

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, upgrade

Just looking for some pointers, guidance and reassurance to make this transition as smooth as possible.

I created an iPhone App and it has been in the store since 2009. Recently i've been inspired to update it, including a couple of new features but also to tidy it up for the higher resolution devices out now.

I've decided to completely re-write the application from the ground up in a new Xcode project.

My questions are:

- What settings do I need to configure in my new Xcode project to ensure it will overwrite and upgrade the original? (is it just Bundle ID and Version Number?)
- Is there a way I can test this on the device / simulator prior to submittal?
- The original project used SQLITE whereas the new project uses Core Data. What is the correct way to migrate the data across?

Let me know if you need further information.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What settings do I need to configure in my new Xcode project to ensure
>   it will overwrite and upgrade the original? (is it just Bundle ID and
>   Version Number?)

Yes, but be sure that the *whole* bundle identifier matches. Only part of the bundle ID is shown in the target's summary pane in Xcode. Not shown in Xcode is the 10-character prefix for the bundle ID. Basically, you should got into the iOS Provisioning Portal, click on 'App ID', and make sure that your provision profile is set up to use the same app ID that you used with the earlier version of the app.

> Is there a way I can test this on the device / simulator prior to submittal?

I'd do that by downloading the app from the App Store. (Obviously, this means that you have to test on a device.) Then try installing a newer copy of the app from Xcode. If the bundle ID's are the same, I believe the newer version should replace the one from the App Store.

> The original project used SQLITE whereas the new project uses Core
>   Data. What is the correct way to migrate the data across?

It's about the same as you'd do to migrate between any two different formats. Make sure that the new version can still read data from the old SQLite data files. Write code that reads the user's data from the old files and then writes it into your new Core Data model. Data migration always seems to be a source of bugs -- it's hard to test that it works perfectly in every situation. Considering that, you might want to suggest that the user sync/back up their data to iTunes before the migration happens, or at least avoid deleting the old files right away.